# TPL DataFlow with Lazy Source / stream of data

Tags: c#, tpl-dataflow

Suppose you have a TransformBlock with configured parallelism and want to stream data trough the block. The input data should be created only when the pipeline can actually start processing it. (And should be released the moment it leaves the pipeline.)

Can I achieve this? And if so how?

Basically I want a data source that works as an iterator.
Like so:

```
public IEnumerable<Guid> GetSourceData()
{
    //In reality -> this should also be an async task -> but yield return does not work in combination with async/await ...
    Func<ICollection<Guid>> GetNextBatch = () => Enumerable.Repeat(100).Select(x => Guid.NewGuid()).ToArray();

    while (true)
    {
        var batch = GetNextBatch();
        if (batch == null || !batch.Any()) break;
        foreach (var guid in batch)
            yield return guid;
    }
}
```

This would result in +- 100 records in memory. OK: more if the blocks you append to this data source would keep them in memory for some time, but you have a chance to get only a subset (/stream) of data.

---

**Some background information:**

I intend to use this in combination with azure cosmos db, where the source could all objects in a collection, or a change feed. Needless to say that I don't want all of those objects stored in memory. So this can't work:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

public async Task ExampleTask()
{
    Func<Guid, object> TheActualAction = text => text.ToString();

    var config = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        BoundedCapacity = 5,
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 15
    };
    var throtteler = new TransformBlock<Guid, object>(TheActualAction, config);
    var output = new BufferBlock<object>();
    throtteler.LinkTo(output);

    throtteler.Post(Guid.NewGuid());
    throtteler.Post(Guid.NewGuid());
    throtteler.Post(Guid.NewGuid());
    throtteler.Post(Guid.NewGuid());
    //...
    throtteler.Complete();

    await throtteler.Completion;
}
```

The above example is not good because I add all the items without knowing if they are actually being 'used' by the transform block. Also, I don't really care about the output buffer. I understand that I need to send it somewhere so I can await the completion, but I have no use for the buffer after that. So it should just forget about all it gets ...

Comment: This *can* work, in fact that's how it should work. You need to use `await SendAsync()` instead of `Post` to block the source if the target buffer is full

Comment: Or you could wrap the iterator function inside a `TransformManyBlock`. Send a single message to it and have it generate messages in a loop

Comment: If you don't care about the output use an ActionBlock instead of a TransformBlock

Comment: In short, I'd suggest you explain what you really want to do. The dataflow library already provides what you ask. There are many ways those things can be combined though - a loop with `await target.SendAsync()` is the simplest way to send messages with backpressure but where is it going to get its data from? Will it block while waiting or can it call an asynchronous method? How's that going to work inside the iterator? That loop It won't be part of the pipeline either. Wrap the loop in a TransformManyBlock then?

Comment: Or create a custom block with `Datablock.Encapsulate()` that reads data asynchronously in a loop and posts to an *InputBuffer*?

Comment: Do you maybe just want to process and insert data in batches? I would not use DataFlow for that. If that's what you want I can suggest something else.

Comment: I do not want to work with batches as such, the goal is to get a consistent but limited usage of RU's within azure cosmos db. A batch would start of at maybe 1000RU's, then at the end of the batch drop to maybe 50RU's and when starting the next batch back up to 1000RU's. In the end I want to get an average of (for example) +- 700 RU's for a given process. And I think I can achieve this by limiting the number of concurrent tasks at the most RU intensive part in the pipeline. All the other blocks can go as fast as they want.

Comment: About the SendAsync() -> that may be what I need. I just don't have a lot of experience with the TPL, so I did not know where to start looking. This seems a good starting point, so Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Post()` will return `false` if the target is full without blocking. While this *could* be used in a busy-wait loop, it's wasteful. `SendAsync()` on the other hand will wait if the target is full :

```
public async Task ExampleTask()
{
    var config = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        BoundedCapacity = 50,
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 15
    };
    var block= new ActionBlock<Guid, object>(TheActualAction, config);

    while(//some condition//)
    { 
        var data=await GetDataFromCosmosDB();
        await block.SendAsync(data);
        //Wait a bit if we want to use polling
        await Task.Delay(...);
    }

    block.Complete();
    await block.Completion;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to process data at a defined degree of parallelism (`MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 15`). TPL dataflow is very clunky to use for such a simple requirement.

There's a very simple and powerful pattern that might solve your problem. It's a parallel async foreach loop as described here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/05/implementing-a-simple-foreachasync-part-2/

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body) 
{ 
    return Task.WhenAll( 
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop) 
        select Task.Run(async delegate { 
            using (partition) 
                while (partition.MoveNext()) 
                    await body(partition.Current); 
        })); 
}
```

You can then write something like:

```
var dataSource = ...; //some sequence
dataSource.ForEachAsync(15, async item => await ProcessItem(item));
```

Very simple.

You can dynamically reduce the DOP by using a `SemaphoreSlim`. The semaphore acts as a gate that only lets N concurrent threads/tasks in. N can be changed dynamically.

So you would use `ForEachAsync` as the basic workhorse and then add additional restrictions and throttling on top.